# Torn between plugging back into the original vs. an intermediate equation...

Tags: calculus

Let's say I am starting with this equation
$$y^2-x^2=2xy-2x+1$$

It can then be determined that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y-1}{y-x}$$

Let's say I want to find all points on the curve where the tangent slope equals 2.

So, I set $\frac{x+y-1}{y-x}=2$ and end up with 
$$y=3x-1$$

This means that all points where the tangent slope is 2 have a y-value that is one less than triple the x-value.   Which are these points?  I sub this into the original equation, and end up with $x=0$ and $x=1$   So, these are the x-values where y is one less than triple the x.

So, here is my dilemma.  Do I sub $x=0$ and $x=1$ into the original equation or just into $y=3x-1$ ?

Initially, I figured since I am looking for points on the original function, is it not more correct to plug $x=0$ and $x=1$ into the original?  This yields 4 solutions ${(0,1)(0,-1)(1,0)(1,2)}$.  However, only ${(0,-1)(1,2)}$ ALSO satisfy the $y=3x-1$.  So, I discard the other two solutions.

Instead, however, if you just sub $x=0$ and $x=1$ directly into $y=3x-1$, you will directly get only the 2 correct solutions ${(0,-1)(1,2)}$   What does this mean?  You have the 2 x-values where $y=3x-1$.  But, since $y-=3x-1$ must be satisfied, you might as well plug it directly into there, right?

Which is the more correct method?

Comment: I prefer plugging into y=3x-1, because you avoid the "extraneous roots" you'd get by plugging into the original.

Comment: But would that happen in every case?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're asking: if you solve the simpler equation, will all of those solutions still solve the original equation. In this case, they do, but, in general, they might not. In particular, if the simpler equation is itself quadratic (or quartic, etc), the simpler one may give you extraneous roots. So, yes, you need to check that the simpler equations solutions still work with the original equation.